# How can I open a locally stored PDF on a web browser in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, pdf

For some reason, when I try to click on this link it tries to redirect me to it, and then reloads the page on a blank http://localhost:4200/ page without displaying the PDF. I had this concept working on another project, and I tried to do the same thing as I did before, but nothing that I'm doing seems to be working. I've made sure that the file exists and I've done my best to give it the correct file path. The file link is in the show-report.component.html as:

```
Report: <a href="backend\PDF\f-1543526335019.pdf" target="_blank">Test</a>
```

**show-report.component.html**

```
<h2>Civil Grand Jury - Reports</h2>

<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let report of reports">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{ report._id }} {{ report.reportNum }}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{ report.reportTitle }}
      </mat-panel-description>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{ report.reportDate }}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    Report: <a href="backend\PDF\f-1543526335019.pdf" target="_blank">Test</a>
    <mat-action-row>
      <button mat-button color="primary">ADD RESPONSE</button>
      <a mat-button color="primary">EDIT REPORT</a>
      <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="openDialog(report)">DELETE</button>
    </mat-action-row>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

**Picture of File Structure:**

[image: File Structure]

Any additional code/resources will be available upon request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check if http://localhost:4200/backend/PDF/f-1543526335019.pdf really exists.

If so, try this

```
<a href="/backend/PDF/f-1543526335019.pdf" target="_blank">Test</a>
```

Also, use forward slashes. Backward slashes are a Windows thing.

Comment: Okay, I just tried: href="PDF\f-1543526335019.pdf", href="PDF/f-1543526335019.pdf", href="backend\PDF\f-1543526335019.pdf", and href="backend/PDF/f-1543526335019.pdf". Unfortunately, nothing worked. I tried to go to that link, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Check your developer tools in your Chrome browser and see which files it loads using the Network tab. Then try to find those files in your project and make sure you place your PDF in the same folder as those files. Then try to access it.

Comment: Maybe the url is catched by your angular application. Then it looks for a route of that form in your routes definitions and as the route is not defined it raises an error that ultimately provokes the redirection to the root of your application. Make sure that the file’s route is not being interpreted by angular and hits the backend as intended. You can help by explaining your app architecture a bit more. Maybe posting your routes will also help